# PIL, im.getdata() returns tuple of different sizes

Tags: python-imaging-library

Sometimes getdata() returns a tuple with four values and other times it returns a tuple with only three.  Why?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(some_image)
assert(len(im.getdata()[0]) == 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image in in RGB mode then the first three values are "R", "G", and "B" values for the image. If it is in RGBA mode then the fourth value is the alpha value. You can check what mode the image is by doing:

```
im.mode
```

You can use .convert to switch the mode of an image. For example:

```
im.covert("RGBA")
```

This would change the image mode to RGBA. Check out the Mode section [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/concepts.htm) for more information on the different modes PIL supports.